# Overcome HTTP basic auth when calling WooCommerce API

Tags: php, wordpress, api, woocommerce

I‘m trying to call the WooCommerce/Wordpress API, but the online shop that I‘m trying to reach has HTTP Basic Autj turned on. That means, I need to authenticate once to overcome the HTTP authentication and then I need to authenticate a second time using the api key in order to use the api. Is there a possibility to make an api call whilst overcoming two levels of authentication?

The problem is that if I try to authenticate, I use the following code:

```php
$headers = array('Accept' => 'application/json');
$options = array('auth' => array($username, $password));
$request = Requests::get("$url/$api/$model", $headers, $options);
```

then I get a 401 (unathorised) response from the api, because I didn't send the api token in my request. But if I use the api token and secret instead of the username and password, I don't even get near the api because I don't overcome the http basic authentication.

Thanks for yout help!

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, you're having an issue calling your website due to HTTP Basic Auth.

When it comes to authentication on `https://your.site`, you can connect to `https://your.site` and enter `foo` as the user and `bar` as the password, OR you can connect to `https://foo:bar@your.site`.

Hope I helped!

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on your question for clarification as I don't have the rep. So here goes with an answer!

I think the answer is that you will not overcome two levels of authentication in one call. You will likely contact the server first for an access token using your username and password.

Basic authorization usually means that in the initial http request you set the headers to include `'Authorization': 'Basic _______________________'` and then in place of the underscores put a long alphanumeric string that is generated by base64-encoding your username and password (that you would log into WooCommerce with I presume) like so: `username:password`, and including that colon in between.

If I actually base64 encode `username:password` it comes out to `dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQK`

so when setting your initial http request headers, include:

`'Authorization' : 'Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQK'`

Except base64 encode you're own username and password (separated by the colon!).

Assuming this works, the api may return an access token to you in a few ways. But if you follow the docs you should be able to figure it out from this point.

Again, really not clear on what you're question is exactly but can't comment so I took a shot. Good luck

Comment: The problem is that if I try to authenticate, I use the following code:

$headers = array('Accept' => 'application/json');
$options = array('auth' => array($username, $password));
$request = Requests::get("$url/$api/$model", $headers, $options);
then I get a 401 (unathorised) response from the api, because I didn't send the api token in my request. But if I use the api token and secret instead of the username and password, I don't even get near the api because I don't overcome the http basic authentication.

Comment: An idea: share the complete request that is sent (using Chrome dev tools or equivalent) including the http headers.